# Unable to use log4j.properties to disable kafka logs from spark application

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-kafka, log4j

I want to disable kafka logs from spark running in kubernetes. I have set in Spark application log4j properties below entries

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, stderr, kafkaAppender
  log4j.logger.Client=INFO, stdout, stderr
  log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
  log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
  log4j.appender.stdout.immediateFlush=true
  log4j.logger.kafka=ERROR, WARN
  log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=ERROR, WARN
  log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer=ERROR, WARN
  log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.streams=ERROR, WARN
  log4j.additivity.org.apache.kafka.streams=false
  log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer=ERROR, WARN
  log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer=ERROR, WARN
  log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState=ERROR, WARN
```

Still I see INFO logs like below in kubernetes driver pod

```
INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer... 
INFO Metadata
INFO AbstractCoordinator
INFO MemoryStore
INFO CodeGenerator
INFO KafkaConsumer: [Consumer
INFO Metadata
```

Am I adding the correct configs in

Comment: Add the package name to the layout format, then you'll know what's logging those. Producers don't have "subscription states", so those aren't Kafka logs

Comment: I added `log4j.appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n%ex` still can not see any chnages in the log fromat. It seems logfile is not getting used

Comment: I am running pyspark kafka streaming job on kubernets, I get these not neccessory logs on driver pod `INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-driver-0-3, groupId=spark-kafka-source-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition dummy-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=5, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka-0.kafka-headless....local:9093 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}` I want to disable thoes. Is it possible with log4j.properties or I need to change someting at  pods log config

Comment: @Panda Here you need to use `sparkContext.setLogLevel()` method in your spark application for disabling Info and Debug level logs, follow this [**article**](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-stop-info-and-debug-logging-console) for more information on how to define this method in your spark application

Comment: I tried adding spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR") but still I see same logs on driver pod :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark [uses log4j2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging) now, which is why log4j.properties will not be picked up.

Inside the containers, you should have some environment variable `SPARK_CONF_DIR`, and in that path, you can set the `log4j2.properties` file.

You can find the default template in the Spark source code - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/log4j2.properties.template

So, turning off kafka might look something like this

```
logger.kafkaClients.name = org.apache.kafka.clients
logger.kafkaClients.level = off
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link. I used log4j2 as well, but still I can see logs. Also I have updated the logs block in a question. I have a kafka streaming pipeline which is running in k8s. I see those logs on driver pod.

Comment: k8s shouldn't matter since logs are the same anywhere. The properties you've shown in the question need to be set in `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/log4j2.properties`, not `log4j.properties` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging

Comment: Or you can set `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=<path to file>`

Comment: Yes I have set this in my submit command already. My submit command config looks like this `--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///logging/etc/log4j2.properties \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///logging/etc/log4j2.properties \
  --conf spark.log4j.debug=true \
  --conf spark.log4j.configuration=file:///logging/etc/log4j2.properties \
  --conf log4j.debug=true \
  --conf log4j.configuration=file:///logging/etc/log4j2.properties \
  --master "k8s://api" \
  --deploy-mode cluster`

Comment: Look at [these 4 lines](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/log4j2.properties.template#L38-L42) for example. They split the level and package between lines, not use `log4j.logger.<package>=<level>` format

Comment: Okay! now I have entries like this  `loggers = kafka, kafka-consumer

logger.kafka.name = org.apache.kafka
logger.kafka.level = warn

logger.kafka-consumer.name = org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer
logger.kafka-consumer.level = info`

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but even after trying this changes I still see same logs.

Comment: Is it because I am creating a log4j.properties in dockerfile at location /logging/etc/  spark submit command is not able to find the file. But when I verified at this path in pod file exists

Comment: 1) Don't use info/warn if you want to turn off those logs 2) As mentioned, `log4j.properties` is the incorrect file name, regardless of where the path exists. You can also use a ConfigMap rather than add to the Dockerfile. In any case Spark does not read any such path on its own. That what the extraJavaOptions are for, but you should mount the file as `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/log4j2.properties` (wherever that shell variable exists) rather than make your own folder, ideally

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, Do you know how to turn on stack traces shown for exceptions in the python code run by spark executors. I am using applyInPandas and can not see errors that happen in python code that has been serialised by spark. I am using logging.conf file and have `logging.config.fileConfig(/conf/logging.conf",
)
log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger("Logexample")
    logger.setLevel(log4jLogger.Level.DEBUG)`

Comment: Log4j is only applicable for JVM classes, not Python. Maybe check the koalas module documentation? Otherwise, please open new post since you've accepted this one

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I already have pipeline running with pandas and want to see full stack traces shown for exceptions in the python code run by spark executors and errors that happen in python code that has been serialised by spark (e.g. in calls to applyInPandas) cannot be retraced. We do get lengthy stack traces for the java code but none for the python code

Comment: I've never used spark with pandas, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The [**official kafka github repo**](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties) contains the list of available options for configuring kafka and log4j. From the list of properties given by you we can see that still few kafka configurations are present. If you want to remove the kafka logs completely, comment them or use the OFF option as given below.

> ```
> log4j.logger.Client=INFO, stdout, stderr
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
> log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
> log4j.appender.stdout.immediateFlush=true log4j.logger.kafka=OFF
> log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=OFF
> log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer=OFF
> log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.streams=OFF
> log4j.additivity.org.apache.kafka.streams=false
> log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer=OFF
> log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer=OFF
> log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState=OFF
> ```

If you just want to remove info level logs for your kafka application from log4j set the below property to higher level and restart the respective services for these settings to applied

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=Error
```

Follow this [**url**](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/logging.html) for detailed information on kafka and log4j integration.

Comment: Thank you for the anwer :)  I am running spark on kubernetes and it seems this log4j.properties file is not being used. I see not chnage in the behaviour when i see pod's  logs.

Comment: These logs i can see on driver pod.  INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer...  INFO SubscriptionState:[Producer...

Comment: @Panda Here you need to use `sparkContext.setLogLevel()` method in your spark application for disabling Info and Debug level logs, follow this [**article**](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-stop-info-and-debug-logging-console) for more information on how to define this method in your spark application

Comment: I tried adding spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR") but still I see same logs on driver pod :(

Comment: @Panda can you paste the code snippet that you are using for writing logs from your spark application and can you confirm whether you are using any cluster manager or operator

Comment: I am using `log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__file__)
    logger.setLevel(log4jLogger.Level.ERROR)` and also  `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")` after building sparkSession. It Spark submit I am using --master "k8s://k8s-api-url" \ --deploy-mode cluster and other configs

Comment: @Panda can you try to set the log level before the sparkSession and check the result

Comment: I still get the same log messages

Comment: @Panda have you restarted the service after making the changes to your file. If you are still facing the problem stop the existing sparkContext and build it again

Comment: I am restarting whole setup so that everything newly created

Comment: 1) The linked file is for the broker, not clients. You'd be better off linking to log4j documentation itself. 2) The linked Kafka Connect logs aren't for Kafka clients, or in Spark

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and solved it after explicitly calling

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties")
```

in the spark application.

Hopefully this works for your case.